# How do I add a configuration variable to my CMake script?

Tags: cmake

I'd like to add a variable that the user must set after clicking "Configure" in cmake-gui. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using the set command, specify CACHE parameters, e.g.

```
set(NAME_INCLUDE "default value" CACHE FILEPATH "description")
set(NAME_LIB "default value" CACHE FILEPATH "description")
```

In the GUI CMake will group all variables with the same prefix.

See the CMake documentation for [set](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aset).

Comment: I just figured this out after looking for a while, so I thought I'd answer my own question with a community wiki answer.

Comment: Why do you need a description ? I used the same but with STRING instead of FILEPATH

Comment: @jamk see the provided link:  "If `CACHE` is present, then the `<variable>` is put in the cache. `<type>` and `<docstring>` are then required."

Comment: And if you find it doesn't work (like I just did), it may be because that variable is getting created elsewhere without the CACHE attribute. I was trying to create a configurable variable called BOOST_ROOT. I ended up changing my variable's name to not conflict with what happens in find_package(Boost).