# Modifying CACHE variable in CMake is not working

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I am using CMake 3.10.2 in Windows.

When I set the variable using CACHE like this

```
SET(ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION 2016)
SET(ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION ${ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION} CACHE STRING "" )
```

When I change the ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION variable to 2014 in GUI, this change is not updated in CMake. It keeps generating for 2016 version.

Please help in this regard.
Thanks in Advance

Edit1:

This is the project structure:

```
|CMakeLists.txt
|FindABAQUS.cmake
|-project1
|---source1.cpp
|---CMakeLists.txt which has SET(ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION 2016 CACHE STRING "")  
|-project2
|---source2.cpp
|---CMakeLists.txt which has SET(ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION 2016 CACHE STRING "")
```

I changed the ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION to 2014 in GUI. The ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION  became 2014 in CMakeCache.txt file. 
But when printed with message(${ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION }) it shows 2016

**Solution:**

```
example: SET(MAJORVERSION 2016 CACHE STRING "")
```

One might need to unset all the Include paths and library paths, to take effect of the new version Include path and library paths.

```
example: UNSET(INCLUDE_PATH CACHE)
         UNSET(LIBRARY_PATH CACHE)
```

Comment: Local variable hides the cached variable declaration.

Comment: I could not understand. Can you please explain in further detail or post a link relevant to this. Thanks

Comment: The linked Q&A does describe it in detail. Your first command sets a local variable `ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION`. You second command sets a cached variable `ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION`. The local variable supersedes the cached variable. If you just wanted to have  a default merge both commands into `SET(ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION 2016 CACHE STRING "")`.

Comment: @Florian: The referenced question and the answer doesn't describe such hiding. So it is hardly a duplicate.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're right. Sorry, have to add it there. But I'm pretty sure we covered that already in some other Q&A. Do you have a fitting duplicate?

Comment: @Florian Thanks for the reply! I still face the same problem. I think I am missing something...  I used `SET(ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION 2016 CACHE STRING "")` , but still could not change it in GUI

Comment: @Arun Just take a look into the `CMakeCache.txt` file in your binary output directory. If it says "2014" the change was successful. Then add a `variable_watch(ABAQUS_MAJORVERSION)` to your main `CMakeLists.txt` to see if some other code part is overwriting your setting.

Comment: @Florian: That question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294269/how-do-i-add-a-configuration-variable-to-my-cmake-script - looks more suitable as a duplicate. However, it is strange that it doesn't work for the question's author. @Arun: When you use [approach suggested by the Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859504/modifying-cache-variable-in-cmake-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment86734741_49859504), have you removed the first `set()` command?

Comment: Please take a look at the edit1. Thanks

Comment: @Arun I have to admit I've never heard of an `EXTERNAL` cache variable type and I can't find a reference in [CMake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry). Is this an undocumented feature and - if so - what exactly does it do?

Comment: @Florian Apologize my misunderstanding. There is no EXTERNAL cache variable in CMake. The dereferencing variables by using UNSET(INCLUDE_PATH CACHE) only updated the newly entered CACHE variables. Without unset, I need to delete the CMakeCache.txt to update. I have corrected the error.

Comment: @arun You shouldn't edit your question in order to answer it. Instead, please [answer your own question!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how you're using (or accidentally *not* using) the cache variable. You can have a normal variable and cache variable of the same name existing at the same time (which is exactly what you have going on) and still access them both (as per [the docs on variable references](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references)) using `${var_name}` for the regular variable, and `$CACHE{var_name}` for the cache variable.

This can trip people up because they aren't used to writing the explicit cache form, because usually [the following behaviour takes effect](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables):

> When evaluating Variable References, CMake first searches the function call stack, if any, for a binding and then falls back to the binding in the current directory scope, if any. If a "set" binding is found, its value is used. ***If an "unset" binding is found, or no binding is found, CMake then searches for a cache entry***. If a cache entry is found, its value is used. Otherwise, the variable reference evaluates to an empty string. The $CACHE{VAR} syntax can be used to do direct cache entry lookups.

I'm guessing this is what's tripping you up.

---

The following scenario can be another cause of confusion for anyone not aware of its behaviour, but I don't think it's what's tripping you up here.

In [the CMake docs for setting cache variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry):

> Since cache entries are meant to provide user-settable values this does not overwrite existing cache entries by default. Use the FORCE option to overwrite existing entries.

For example, [cache variables can be set on the command line with `-D var_name:TYPE=VALUE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options).